# How set checked on input in iframe? Webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, iframe, webbrowser-control

I want set atrribute "checked" in iframe.
I tried to use InvokeScript for this.

```
string jCode = "$(\"iframe\").contents().find(\".checkbox - class\")
               .prop("checked", true)";
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { jCode });
```

And i see error: accses denied.
As far as I know this is because I'm trying to change the cross-domain iframe HTTPS. Webbrowser C#. How set checked on input in iframe?

Comment: Yes that's right. And what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a website and any unauthorised persons can use simple iframe element to hijack user session with cross-domain javascript functions.

What you want to do is a security breach and this is not allowed by any decent security-aware browser.